# Paginação em Codeigniter com erro Type: Error Message: Unsupported operand types

Tags: php, codeigniter, lógica

Tenho uma função que pega todos os valores do banco de dados e manda para uma *view*, então estou fazendo uma paginação. Só que quando coloco o

```
 $this->pagination->create_links()
```

da variável `array` ele dá um erro:

Onde o erro é esse:

```
Type: Error

Message: Unsupported operand types

Filename: /var/www/html/idbl/system/libraries/Pagination.php
```

Quando eu tiro o

```
$this->pagination->create_links()
```

Ele volta a funcionar.

Vou passar aqui a minha função completa:

```
public function artigo_all() {
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url('site/artigo_all');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->artigo->GetAll(false, "artigo_id", 'asc');
    $config['per_page'] = 3;
    $qnt = $config['per_page'];
    ($this->uri->segment(3) != "") ? $inicio = $this->uri->segment(3) : $inicio = 0;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $dados = array(
        'titulo' => 'Todos os artigos',
        'artigo' => $this->artigo->GetAll(false, "artigo_id", 'asc', $qnt, $inicio),
        'jeans' => $this->jeans->GetAll(false, 'jeans_id', 'asc'),
        'aniverMes' => $this->aniver->aniversarianteMes(),
        'aniverDes' => $this->aniver->aniversarianteMes(),
        'paginacao' => $this->pagination->create_links(),
    );

    $this->template->load('front/tema_front', 'front/todos_artigos', $dados);
}
```

O que pode ser?

Comment: Natan tem essa linha que não está fazendo nada: `($this->uri->segment(3) != "") ? $inicio = $this->uri->segment(3) : $inicio = 0;` eu to achando que seria `$inicio = ($this->uri->segment(3) != "") ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;` tem também outros problemas `total_rows` está mesmo retornando a quantidade de registro? e dentro do array `$dados` tem duas chaves que é atribuido o mesmo valor `$this->aniver->aniversarianteMes()` porque? Tem bastante erros por isso da um `exception Unsupported operand types`

Comment: Nem tinha reparado isso , agora eu arrumei muito obrigado.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver tudo?

Comment: Tudo ainda bem. Muito Obrigado rray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito provavelmente seu problema esta quando define o valor da variável:
`$config['total_rows']` , Ou seja, em sua controladora, verifique o método e ou retorno (valor) do método, que esta atribuindo valor a variável:

> $config['total_rows'] = 200; //valor inteiro